# Android Double is Too Precise

Tags: java, android

I am using a Double to send latitude and longitude over the internet to a server, but the value is:

```
2.1188253687859282E155
```

Is there any way to make this let precise?  I only really need the first six numbers after the "."
Such as

```
2.118825
```

Is there any way to do this? If so how?

Many thanks

Comment: *How* do you send the values to the server - a tcp channel? A text channel? An http post? A SOAP service request?

Comment: TCP Socket using a ByteBuffer which is in LittleEndian

Comment: It might be better to let the client send data as precise as possible and let the server truncate it. This way if you change your mind about the amount of precision you need, you only have to change the server.

Comment: Another issue is that he also sends me a double (latitude and longitude) which then I convert as a stupidly long number. I will play around at work tomorrow and see what I can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [DecimalFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
DecimalFormat formatter= new DecimalFormat("00.000000");//Your precision specified in the number of zeroes.
formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);//In Case you need rounding
String s=formatter.format(double_val).toString();
```

Comment: The issue with DecimalFormat is that the server has no idea what DecimalFormat is as it is written in Delphi 2007.

Comment: Unless putting it back as a double would then keep it down to the precision defined...

Comment: @apmartin1991: I haven't written a script in Delphi but i do believe any string that holds a numeric value can be parsed as such to the same degree of precision as it posseses on any Server Side Script.Also OP hasn't suggested anything to do with Delphi in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I could write it as a string, it would be easy to convery a string to a double in Delphi, I was just hoping to still retain using a double to keep the code much tidier. If I were to convert a decimal format to a double would it still be over precise or would it then be limited by the precision of the decimal format?

Comment: We'll there isnt(althought you could use float but its precision also far exceeds what you desire) there is a reason for the same as operations/calculations compromising of those datatypes have that many bits allocated ,so no matter you assign a float as **float x=3.1519f;**  it'll still be stored as 3.151900000... Rest is just display

Comment: Very late reply, but in the end I used this method and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
formatter.format(value);
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but I'd recommend you add some explanation to it. Code-only answers may be good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of:

```
 (long) ((int)(d * 1000000)) / 1000000;
```

Comment: That's wrong. `long`/`int` = `long`, which cannot give a non-integer result.

Comment: `double d = 1.45768345893476789;
println((long) (d * 1000000) / 1000000d);` prints 1.457683 as required though; note the `d` on the last 1000000.

Comment: I tried something similar to this but no matter what the value of 'd' was the result was always 0.0